# How can ı data structure in firestore for surveyApp

Tags: database, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a survey application with Kotlin. I tried hard, but I couldn't get the firestore data structure in place. I tried such a way, but I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help?

[image: ı tried like this]
[image]

[image: This is kotlin code]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Besides that, please also explain what exactly would you like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but you are querying on the collection `abc` twice in a row in your code which is in any case wrong.

Change

```
firestore.collection(collectionPath: "abc").document(document.id).collection(collectionPath: "edf")
```

To

```
firestore.document(document.id).collection(collectionPath: "edf")
```

And please, when you post a question on SO with some code, copy the code directly, dont take a screenshot